# Apple requires user permission to use compass?

Tags: ios, location, compass

We are about to submit and iOS app, and we would like to know:  it is necessary to get the user permission to access the compass? Is the compass considered as a part of the location services, in terms of the user privacy?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It doesn't require user permission. For compass feature, you must be using [**UIAccelerometer** class](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAccelerometer_Class/index.html) and that is open-access API from Apple framework. So any developer can use that feature in their application.

Comment: Thanks Mrunai. The point is I'm working with an Xcode project generated by Unity so I need to check exactly how is Unity using the libraries.

Comment: Even there, any framework will use UIAccelerometer internally for Compass feature. Because that's the only API provided by Apple. So for this particular feature it won't be required. It requires, if you are using microphone, camera, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tested this out and found that user permission is not required for either the Core Motion or Core Location device heading.

Comment: Thanks Rowan! I have to check it carefully cause it is a project exported from Unity, so I don't know exactly what libraries is using.